# CSS 2 colors at 50% opacity == other color

Tags: css, math, colors

I have 2 div's both at 50% opacity and when these 2 divs overlap each other they should match my final hex color of:

```
#66984D
```

with HSB (not HSL!) values:

```
Hue: 100deg
Saturation: 50%
Brightness: 60%
```

HSL values:

```
Hue: 100deg
Saturation: 33%
Lightning: 45%
```

Can this be calculated? I also prefer not to use 2 totally different colors but 2 ALMOST the same.

[image]

Comment: While it doesn't answer your question, this may prove for some interesting reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190432/2-opposite-opacity-values-dont-produce-opaque-color

Comment: Here is the reason they're not the same color -- you're laying one 50% opacity div on top of another. This actually creates a 75% opacity color, not a 100% opacity color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that your desired color is `x`, and it will be made up of a 50% opacity version of another color `y` times itself.  This gives us this equation: `x = .5y * .5y`.  Assuming my algebra is correct, this translates to `y = 2 * squareroot(x)`.

Your `x` is #66984D - that's 102 R, 152 G, 77 B.  Plug that through the equation, and your starting color should be roughly 20 R, 25 G, and 18 B.  In hex, that's #143712.